# mysql & php auto increment id and insert data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two database tables in my sql database. First one is personal table and other one is payment details. Auto inctiment id in personal table is used as foreign key of payment details. i have to insert data to two this table at a time.normaly I should insertdata to personal table and get auto increment id of this row and insert data to payment data table. but i have some problems.

- I can't get auto increment id using my sql SELECT query
  easily.because there are more colums to check through WHERE.
- get last insert id is not perfect way. because other user can insert 
  another person's data while i'm accessing and i receive wrong id.

I have no good knowledge about this. help me !

Comment: Please insert what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know your structure, but the best best way here is to use transactions. Link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT /* Your insertion into personalTable */
SELECT @lastId:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO paymentTable SET (user_id) VALUES (@lastId);
COMMIT;
```

Also you need to set your TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL to SERIALIZABLE to prevent any transaction violations.

UPD. Thanks @Drew to make me dig deeper.

Comment: No, as remote the possibility of a problem, that is not the way one does it. Between your insert and your variable save in line 3, another user could have done an insert. One uses `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to safely get that data. That function returns the last insert id for *your* client connection.

Comment: You're right, but LAST_INSERT_ID() also can't prevent insert while this transaction is working. The best way here is to set isolation level to SERIALIZABLE, so your transactions will be fully independent. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html

Comment: why would we want to prevent an insert? We are trying to get the correct `@lastId` in all cases and your answer is faulty.

Comment: @Drew "Between your insert and your variable save in line 3, another user could have done an insert." LAST_INSERT_ID() can't affect it without isolation, but of course it's much better than MAX(id).

Comment: Jaro, it is not affecting it, it is safely getting it bro ... +1 for research effort. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, mate) Hope it will somehow help the asker.